# New to Google Code - How to apply a patch

Tags: patch, google-code, markdownsharp

I've been using MarkdownSharp for a while, but after reading a twitter post from [@Nick_Craver](http://twitter.com/#!/Nick_Craver/status/107779250655989760), I was thinking about adding `rel="nofollow"` to my implementation as well.

I see there's already a patch for it, and I figure that instead of re-writing it, this could be a learning experience on applying a patch.

Just wondering if anyone could let me know exactly how patches are added to an existing solution?

[Here's the patch](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/issues/attachmentText?id=35&aid=-8955943162754809755&name=MarkdownSharp-NoFollowLinks.patch&token=812dfe35ff6e30e59909b81e071937d2) I'm doing this with.

#### EDIT

I've done some browsing around, and found a `git` command that applies a patch, but I'm thinking that since I don't use git... there must be another way ?!?!